# How do I disable texture filtering for sprite scaling in XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, sprites, spritesheet

I have a sprite that I'm trying to scale up in XNA, but XNA is applying some sort of texture filtering that smooths it and makes it look ugly. I'd like it to just do pixel doubling instead of interpolation. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to set the sampler state. The default for SpriteBatch is `SamplerState.LinearClamp` (ie: linear interpolation - the smooth/blurry one).

Choose one of the [`SpriteBatch.Begin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.begin.aspx) calls that takes a `SamplerState` and pass in `SamplerState.PointClamp` (selects the pixel at that precice "point").

Answer (score 13):

Just in case someone else is wondering how to do this outside of a sprite batch, you would do this just before rendering your primitives:

```
this.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;
```

This has to be done on every frame, if there are other items in your rendering pipeline that would change this value (like a `SpriteBatch`).

Comment: Yep! And just for the sake of completeness, there's also a `SamplerState.PointWrap` if you'd like texture wrapping to take place (while still disabling texture filtering). Or if you need your own custom behavior, you can create a new `SamplerState` object to fit any custom needs, and change the `Filter` property to `TextureFilter.Point`.