# Sprites rendering blurry with velocity

Tags: xna, graphics, monogame

After adding velocity to my game, I feel like my textures are twitching. I thought it was just my eyes, until I finally captured it in a screenshot:

[image]

The one on the left is what renders in my game; the one on the right is the original sprite, pasted over. (This is a screenshot from Photoshop, zoomed in 6x.)

Notice the edges are aliasing -- it looks almost like sub-pixel rendering. In fact, if I had not forced my sprites (which have position and velocity as ints) to draw using integer values, I would swear that MonoGame is drawing with floating point values. But it isn't.

What could be the cause of these things appearing blurry? It doesn't happen without velocity applied.

To be precise, my `SpriteComponent` class has a `Vector2 Position` field. When I call `Draw`, I essentially use `new Vector2((int)Math.Round(this.Position.X), (int)Math.Round(this.Position.Y))` for the position.

I had a bug before where even stationary objects would jitter -- that was due to me using the straight `Position` vector and not rounding the values to `ints`. If I use `Floor`/`Ceiling` instead of round, the sprite sinks/hovers (one pixel difference either way) but still draws blurry.

Comment: Could this be related to the texture filtering being applied?

Comment: Do you have the code for your shader? Some people add half a pixel on both axis to get the pixels centered. Not sure though, I think that's a DirectX only thing.

Comment: @OriginalDaemon what is texture filtering? I don't recall setting it

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager I don't have any shaders (`Effect` instances). Just straight `SpriteBatch` drawing. My origin point is set to the top-left corner here, and I've edited my question to mention (at the end) how I round from float to int to draw.

Comment: Removing texture filtering should solve this but looks bad in movement. [DirectX 9 is strange sometimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690(v=vs.85).aspx) Try to substract (0.5, 0.5) from the final position.

Comment: Could you try [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/6822/22198)?

Comment: Hmm, it depends on the coordinate system used, but I think rounding the Position to the integer probably aligns it to the center of a pixel, not the edge, so subtracting 0.5 should solve this but the problem is not related to the link I posted.

Comment: Deactivating filtering is a workaround not a solution.

Comment: @Archy the final position is an integer, and everything looks great without velocity set. See the bottom of my post; rounding doesn't have anything to do with the blurring.

Comment: Then I need more information: How is velocity implemented? Perhaps the size of the sprite changed? How do you interface with xna, how do the draw calls look like? When clamping the position to pixel boundaries texture filtering is indeed useless in your case. Using floats as position looks better for animated objects.

Comment: @Archy let me know what you need to know. Velocity increments the `sprite.Position`, which is a `float`; the draw calls are documented in my question already (creates a new Vector2 with integer X/Y values rounded from the floats)

Comment: Rendering doesn't know anything about your velocity, so either the position, size or anything else your pass along to SpriteBatch.Draw is different or the error was present before you added velocity. How do you call SpriteBatch.Draw exactly?

Comment: @Archy: `this.X` and `this.Y` are integer versions of the `position` vector which are rounded. The exact call is: `spriteBatch.Draw(this.texture, new Vector2(this.X, this.Y), null, Color.White * this.Alpha, this.Angle, this.origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);`

Comment: @ashes999 did you debug this call and checked this.X, this.Y and this.origin? What is this.origin set to? There is basically no way the render result is different when this Draw call is the same.

Comment: @Archy I'll check when I get home from work. Origin is set to (0, 0) in this specific case. You're right, it sounds weird -- that's why I opened a question for it.

Comment: Show your code. The draw call in the comment above doesn't match up with your "When I call Draw, I essentially use..." statement in your question. It is clearly showing signs of a bilinearly filtered texture being rendered at a position offset slightly from zero, so I think your X and Y values are not what you believe them to be.

Comment: @Archy please add an answer with your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing.

It turns out that **I was not drawing using integer positions, but float positions.** Archy pointed me down the right path with his comment `@ashes999 did you debug this call and checked this.X, this.Y and this.origin?`

As soon as I added a trace statement, I noticed that nothing traced out. It turns out that my `SpriteComponent` class correctly used integer values, but my `SpriteSheetComponent` still used float values from the raw `Vector2 Position`.

Although I didn't try texture filtering and clamping, I was suspicious that these were not the correct change, because I was drawing a 2D image at the same width and height as the source image (no scaling).

Comment: Done, glad you found it!

Answer (score 2):

XNA uses DirectX9 which uses the center of the pixel as its location. This is noticeable when using the Vector2 based overloads of the draw class. I believe that subtracting (.5, .5) should fix your problem.

[More info here.](http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/)

Comment: I can't technically do this, because I'm passing in a Vector2 with `int, int` as the arguments. Besides which, things look perfectly fine when I don't have any objects in motion.

Comment: What do you mean by the object is in motion? XNA has no notion of motion it draws things where you tell it too. Its a series of stationary snapshots. Also try using the Rectangle overloads since you are rounding to a rectangle anyways.

Comment: I have my own implementation of velocity. `SpriteComponent` has a `Vector2` position, which increments as floats depending on the velocity; when I draw, I create a new `Vector2` with integer (rounded) versions of my `position` X and Y. This is not the issue, since stationary objects without velocity appear fine.

Comment: So your saying that you have a position vector p and a velocity vector v, add them such as p += v, then create a copy of p using rounded values. And that this yeild different values then having a position that is the same as the previous p += v despite the draw calls being identical? Because that makes no sense.

Comment: Yep, that's what @Archy is saying too. Let me debug and check again. I add `p += v` during `Update`, and render with `new Vector2((int)Math.Round(p.X), (int)Math.Round(p.Y)))`.

Comment: So shouldn't `new Vector2((int)Math.Round(p.X-0.5f), (int)Math.Round(p.Y-0.5f)))` do the deal?

Answer (score 2):

Rendering doesn't know anything about your velocity, so either the position, size or anything else your pass along to SpriteBatch.Draw is different or the error was present before you added velocity. How do you call SpriteBatch.Draw exactly?

Did you debug this call and checked this.X, this.Y and this.origin? What is this.origin set to? There is basically no way the render result with velocity is different when this Draw call is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that texture filtering is turned on.  If you're not sure what that means, consider a situation where you have a image that is 2 pixels wide:  The first pixel is black, the second pixel is white.  If you zoom in on this texture, if texture filtering is on, you will see that it gets blurry and that the area between the black and white pixel uses a gradient gray color.

A classic example of games with and without filtering are Super Mario 64 which had filtering while Doom did not.

When you don't use velocity, your Sprite is likely positioned so that the center of the texture is at the sample point that XNA (or whatever underlying api is being used) is grabbing the color.  When you move with a float velocity, then the position of your Sprite changes, thus the sample point may not line up directly with the center of a pixel, so the end result is that a color that is an average of the nearest pixels is being used to render.

You can verify that filtering is turned on by simply rendering your Sprite really large on screen.  If it's blurry, then that's the issue.

If you must have pixel-perfect accuracy in rendering, you will want to have a float value for position stored off somewhere, but use integer values for the position of the object you are rendering...or of course you could just turn off filtering if your game doesn't need it.

You may also want to read [this](http://www.flatredball.com/frb/docs/index.php?title=Filtering).

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, I'm already using integers for my location, and the original image size, when I call `Draw`. So I'm not sure how that could be the case -- but I'll try rendering large-scale and seeing if turning off texture filtering will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your SamplerState to SamplerState.PointClamp in the SpriteBatch.Begin call.