# (XNA) Stretching Images (Sprites) without Blur (Rasterizing?)

Tags: xna, screen, rasterization

thanks for clicking on this question although it has likely one of the most un-specific and confusing titles on this site. I am somewhat new to XNA and I have only posted 1 question on this site before which I didn't understand the answer to fully, but I'll give it another go.

I am looking to create a game which allows the user to either go full-screen or re-size the window to a few preset values, like many mainstream games nowadays allow you to do.
I believe I know how to do this in XNA, the problem is, when I toggle full-screen, and it stretches the sprites, they appear blurry.

I know this is a very obvious problem, as stretching = blur (logically). The thing is, I was wondering if there was a way to make it so regardless of the zoom, your sprites look crisp and not blurry? I asked a friend of mine in real life and he said something about rasterizing (which i don't know anything about). The only other thing I can think of

I've seen this done a few times in Flash. For examples of what I mean the only game I can think of is Super Smash Flash 2. It seems regardless of the screen size, most of the sprites and images appear crisp, even on the largest of screens.

If anybody knows anything about this, please share!
-Thanks.

Comment: Mipmapping. You need to keep images of different sizes and switch between them as the level of detail requires. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap

Answer (score 1):

[How do I disable texture filtering for sprite scaling in XNA 4.0?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/how-do-i-disable-texture-filtering-for-sprite-scaling-in-xna-4-0)

This looks like it might be a solution for you. It seems the textures are being sample in such a way that when one pixel on the screen lies between two texture pixels, it's interpolating the colours. You can change it so it uses the closest pixel colour instead. This will look blocky, but less blurry.

http://gregs-blog.com/2008/01/14/how-to-turn-off-bilinear-filtering-in-opengl/

This gives a good explanation of what's going on. It's OpenGL, but the important part is the concept of the texture filtering.