# MonoGame - Scale Texture2D from 16x16 to 64x64

Tags: c#, monogame

I need to scale a Texture2D (let's say it's 16x16) to 64x64.

I tried scaling it in the SpriteBatch#Draw method, but it doesn't look like pixel art as soon as it's drawn, more like a lot of anti-aliasing happened.

I chose 64x64 because 16x16 is pretty small, and I thought I could just scale every pixel by 4 (1x1 pixel in 16x16 could be 4x4 pixels in 64x64), basically I don't want MonoGame to anti-alias when I draw the scaled Texture.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use SamplerState.PointClamp in the SpriteBatch.Begin call.

To quote [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/how-do-i-disable-texture-filtering-for-sprite-scaling-in-xna-4-0):

> You need to set the sampler state. The default for SpriteBatch is SamplerState.LinearClamp (ie: linear interpolation - the smooth/blurry one).
>
> Choose one of the SpriteBatch.Begin calls that takes a SamplerState
>   and pass in SamplerState.PointClamp (selects the pixel at that precice
>   "point").