# XNA's SpriteBatch resizing is not sharp as i use it

Tags: c#, tilemap, spritebatch, tilesets, monogame-extended

I draw a TiledMap with TiledSharp and i've introduced a resize factor when drawing, that looks like this:

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(TileSet                                                   // The input Texture2D
                 , new Rectangle((int)x                                    // The tile rectangle
                                 , (int)y
                                 , tileWidth * ScaleFactor
                                 , tileHeight * ScaleFactor)
                 , tilesetRec                                              // The tile offset on tileset texture
                 , Color.White);                                           // just white
```

> (note: it's not formated on different lines in my code, it's just i'm making it such way that anyone can understand without having previous lines)

but when i start the game it end up really blured and has some Strange outline
[image]

Can someone help me getting really sharp tiles instead of this?

N.B: i Don't want to resize the tileset file, it's to complicated for later modifications regarding the 16x16 style i want for my game. also i'm using Tiled to generate the Tiled Map but i Don't think this last info is relevent.

Comment: also, is it normal that stackexchange remove any form of civilization ("hi", "hello" ...)?

Comment: [Does this help with your issue](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/how-do-i-disable-texture-filtering-for-sprite-scaling-in-xna-4-0)? And yes, it's normal. We prefer a straight-to-the point style for Q&A on this site, so folks get to your question and you get to your answers as efficiently as possible. 

Comment: I'll try out @DMGregory i come back here after

Comment: Well Thanks it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'll close this question as a duplicate for now, to direct folks who find it via search to the existing answers. If you need something different, please feel free to edit the question or post a new question.

Comment: yep thanks a lot you like saved my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DMGregory, i've Added the parametter samplerState on SpriteBatch.Begin that fixed everything

```
SpriteBatch.Begin(transformMatrix: DisplayOffsetMatrix, samplerState: SamplerState.PointClamp);
```

[image]